# ¿Es incorrecto decir claridez?

Tags: gramática

Siempre utilicé la palabra claridad, pero después de escuchar algunas personas repetir muchas veces claridez, me puse a buscar si era también válido decirlo así. La RAE cuando buscas claridez en Google redirige a claridad y no existe la entrada en el sitio oficial. Pero existen hasta canciones: [Claridez](https://www.google.com/search?q=alejandro%20ferradas%20claridez&si=AC1wQDApU_L7mEr08NL2tyPAiwbkKXiOQMzKp1cMwbGxhXrbjF4ef68IpzL1P-xR2OUnHdLHSI6H3cwx7YmxQG5f-bN_BuRhlFmSHOw90FkiPkwvsqZaCaSxNvjfxgx61nnaiZWxWiemMREPVGeUqimD-61pbqdzm7upDjOjTu8C8_54DexYgs3Q-4RZ7GPjrkJ9LnwsLPLY&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNvLypz-T4AhUVrZUCHcgnCb8Q6RN6BAgzEAE&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1) y traducciones [Ejemplos claridez](https://www.ingles.com/ejemplos/claridez) donde la usan.

¿Es incorrecto decir claridez?

Comment: @今夜九 El Español tiene ciertas reglas de gramática y sino las cumples de seguro esa palabra es incorrecta.

Comment: Ej: existen reglas de Ortografía, de uso de sufijos, etc. no las conozco todas.

Answer (score 2):

En el idioma Español aparecen palabras como claridad, clareza (en desuso)...

- CLARIDAD. (Del lat. claritas, -atis.) f. Calidad de
  claro. 51 «Esta claridad que tiene en los ojos este
  animal, la tiene assí mismo en el lomo.»
- CLAREZA. (De claro.) f. desús. Claridad. U «Las
  armas eran frescas y ricas, e con la clareza del sol
  que en ellas feria las hacía muy resplandecientes.

Teniendo esto presente, la palabra "Claridez", aunque puede existir y ser utilizada por un grupo amplio de personas dentro de una comunidad, está no se encuentra aún recogida "oficialmente" y por tanto, su uso debe de ser limitado y así entendido como incorrecto, ya que puede llevar a confusión.

Este tipo de palabras como "claridez" están asociadas a la creación de nuevas palabras por derivación y composición, y en la comprensión de nuevos términos en varios ámbitos. Así, en el mundo jurídico, se ha podido escuchar por ejemplo "*es necesario que ustedes que lo tienen claro, trasmitan esa sensación de "claridez" a la niña*". Sin embargo, la creación de nuevos términos es arriesgada y es necesario que el tiempo decida, por el uso habitual y continuo de las mismas, si su futuro será la incorporación o no, al léxico oficial del diccionario de una comunidad.

Por otro lado, este tipo de expresiones no son habituales en el Español de España, especulandose que "claridez", sea un producto más propio de países Hispano-americanos por la influencia e influjo del Inglés y Español de EEUU, "clarity" (clariti), y en su lectura fonética como (**ˈklerədē**), más asemejada a la voz "Claridez", y que puede derivar hacia una propia o nueva fórmula de expresiones adoptadas para el Español de la voz "Claridad" o matices de ésta, poniendo en cualquier caso de manifiesto, la confusión y el choque entre un préstamo adaptado, préstamo lingüístico, con las palabras parecidas y ya existentes en la propia lengua que la acoge y que en su evolución podrían adoptar igual o distinto significado metafórico (falsos amigos) con aquellas palabras con las que en principio se suelen identificar.

Answer (score 2):

La verdad es que **claridez** es un uso incorrecto, ya que es una palabra no reconocida por la Academia de la lengua.

Sí es correcto usar **clareza**, que es un sinónimo de claridad, y así está aceptado por el Diccionario de la RAE.

Otra forma aceptada es **lucencia**:

> 1. f. p. us. Claridad, resplandor.

El término *lucencia* ya era utilizado en época tan temprana como el siglo XIII, por **Gonzalo de Berceo**:

> Entró una lucencia grand e maravillosa 
> por medio de la cueva que era tenebrosa;

Gonzalo de Berceo: *Vida de Santo Domingo de Silos*, 708.